# What is a mathematical symbol for the angle of two sub-spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Assume you have two subspaces $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$. In general, these are matrices that the span of the columns makes the subspace.

Now: What is the best symbol for denoting the angle of these two subspaces?
I was about to use this $\phi=<\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}>$, but that's only common for inner product of vectors, beside that it is not understood as angle.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean **angle** between two subspaces? What would be an "angle" between a zero space and a line in 3-dimensional vector space

Comment: Sometimes $\angle (E,F)$.

Comment: there is also a matlab function for this angle=subspace[A,B]. sometimes it cannot be defined but for simple cases the angle is welldefined.